# NVIDIA GT610 card with KSP

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have new graphics card for my PC, it's ASUS branded NVIDIA Geforce GT 610 with 1 GB RAM. PC is three years old ASUS motherboard without any extras, just dual core CPU with 6 GB RAM plus hd and DVD drive. I want to get KSP working on this. It has been running, but was very slow and after some while did crash the machine. I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in 32-bit mode for compatibility and stability reasons, at least I hoped them to be better than newer versions and 64-bit version.

I bought graphics card to improve the performance, but found new problems. I got it installed, BIOS does recognice new card and I got drivers installed thanks to help from 
[Trying to install Proprietory Nvidia Graphics Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332026/trying-to-install-proprietory-nvidia-graphics-drivers)

It seems to be there as command 'glxinfo | grep renderer' returns:

OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2

I assume that GPU is not used as **System Settings > Additional Drivers** shows few NVIDIA drivers activated but not currently used. Playing video loads CPU between 30 to 50%, as earlier.

After installation KSP stopped to launch, instead it crashes when loading "Squad Parts"

Any ideas what to do next? Changing NVIDIA card to other manufacturer might not do miracle, based on what I read...

Is there any sw to test graphics card functionality? Have seen Cuda graphic demos mentioned, but did not found them (easily) :(

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436108/looking-to-change-gpus/436114#436114) for info about CUDA graphics in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card is not fully compatible with the driver that you installed. Instead install the tested graphics driver from Additional Drivers:

1. Open Additional Drivers from your menu.
2. Select the topmost driver. It should have `tested` in parenthesis.
3. Hit install and wait for the driver to install
4. Reboot your computer.